# Understanding signature of function traverse in haskell

Tags: haskell, type-signature

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

Hi,
There are a lot of functions that I can't understand signature. Of course I understan that traverse get two arguments, that first is function.  However,
what does mean `(a -> f b)` ? I can understand `(a -> b)`.
Similary, `t a`, `f (t b)`

Could you explain it me ?

Comment: `f` stands for a type constructor (think `f = Maybe`) so does `t` (think `t = []`) - can you understand `(a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe [b]`?

Comment: if you want to get a feeling for this case you can play a bit with ``traverse (\ a -> if even a then Just (a `div` 2) else Nothing) [2,4,6]`` (try changing the input list) ;)

Comment: Thanks. Tell me please: t a always means [a] ?

Comment: Addionally, Why we are using  traverse instead of map ?

Comment: to the first question: no! `t a = [a]` is just an example (that's the reason why you want to have the *parametric* `t` in the first place)

Comment: to the next: try it - what is the difference between `traverse` and `map` (hint: it's `t (f b)` vs `f (t b)` ^^)

Comment: Do you know what `Applicative` means here? Do you know what `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)` means?

Comment: `t` is a constraint specified by the typeclass definition itself, which is why it does not appear in `traverse` as an explicit constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`traverse` is a type class-ed function so sadly the behaviour of this function depends on what exactly we choose `t` to be. This is not dis-similar to `>>=` or `fmap`. However there are rules for it's behaviour, just like in those cases. The rules are supposed to capture the idea that `traverse` takes a function `a -> f b`, which is an effectful transformation from `a` to `b` and lifts it to work on a whole "container" of `a`s, collecting the effects of each of the local transformations.

For example, if we have `Maybe a` the implementation of `traverse` would be

```
 traverse f (Just a) = Just <$> f a
 traverse f Nothing = pure Nothing
```

For lists

```
 traverse f [a1, a2, ...] = (:) <$> f a1 <*> ((:) <$> f a2 <*> ...))
```

Notice how we're taking advantage of the fact that the "effect" `f` is not only a functor, but applicative so we can take two f-ful computations, `f a` and `f b` and smash them together to get `f (a, b)`. Now we want to come up with a few laws explaining that *all* traverse can do is apply `f` to the elements and build the original `t a` back up while collecting the effects on the outside. We say that

```
 traverse Identity = Identity -- We don't lose elements
 t . traverse f = traverse (t . f) -- For nicely composing t
 traverse (Compose . fmap g . f) = Compose . fmap (traverse g) . traverse f
```

Now this looks quite complicated but all it's doing is clarifying the meaning of "Basically walks around and applies the local transformation". All this boils down to is that while you cannot just read the signature to understand what `traverse` does, an OK intuition for the signature is

- We get a local, effectful function `f :: a -> f b`
- A functor full of `a`s
- We get back a functor full of `b` gotten by repeatedly applying `f`, ala `fmap`
- All the effects of `f` are accumulated so we get `f (t b)`, not just `t b`.

Remember though, `traverse` can get used in some weird ways. For example, the lens package is chock-full of using `traverse` with very strange functors to great effect.

As a quick test, can you figure out how to use a legal `traverse` to implement `fmap` for `t`? That is

```
fmapOverkill :: Traversable f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

Or `headMay`

```
headMay :: Traversable t => t a -> Maybe a
```

Both of these are results of the fact that traversable instances also satisfy `Functor` and `Foldable`!